# Update rows from data in another table using corresponding unique ID's

Tags: mysql

Total newbie, trying to figure it out. wrote a bad query and deleted a majority of the first and last names in my master customer table. I have the names in different tables but can t seem to figure out how to insert just the names `first` and `last` into my master table according to each unique id.

This is what I have tried so far and totally in over my head.

```
UPDATE `Master_table` SET `first` = (SELECT `first` FROM `table_1`) WHERE `id` IN(SELECT `id` FROM `table_1`);
```

Any help and mercy would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to hear about the deletions. I can see where you are going with your query, but correlated subqueries are not allowed in an `UPDATE` statement (although you didn't correlate here, which is where the problems really started). Instead:

```
UPDATE Master_table, table_1 
SET master_table.first = table_1.first, 
    master_table.last = table_1.last 
WHERE master_table.id = table_1.id;
```

You can dive in deeper on [MySQL's UPDATE help page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html). But the basic idea is to list the tables involved in the `UPDATE` clause, and their relation (like a join) in the `WHERE` clause. Then your `SET` is pretty straightforward.

Comment: awesome, thank you JNevill! Ill read up more as you recommended.